# this.user().context is undefined - Jovo Framework - Alexa

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, voice, jovo-framework

I'm currently using Jovo for cross platform developing Alexa and Google Assistant's skills/actions.

I currently hit a roadblock in which I'm trying to get the previous intent by doing either:
    `this.user().context.prev[0].request.intent` or 
`this.user().getPrevIntent(0)`.

But it hasn't worked. I get `context is undefined` and `getPrevIntent` doesn't exist. According to the [Docs](https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/data/user), I need to set up a table with DynamoDB (I did, and verified that it's working since Jovo is able to store the user object), and passed in the default configuration to App. But still can't seem to get it work. Any ideas?

```
const config = {
  logging: false,
  // Log incoming JSON requests.
  // requestLogging: true,
  /**
   * You don't want AMAZON.YesIntent on Dialogflow, right?
   * This will map it for you!
   */
  intentMap: {
    'AMAZON.YesIntent': 'YesIntent',
    'AMAZON.NoIntent': 'NoIntent',
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': 'HelpIntent',
    'AMAZON.RepeatIntent': 'RepeatIntent',
    'AMAZON.NextIntent': 'NextIntent',
    'AMAZON.StartOverIntent': 'StartOverIntent',
    'AMAZON.ResumeIntent': 'ContinueIntent',
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': 'CancelIntent',
  },
  // Configures DynamoDB to persist data
  db: {
    awsConfig,
    type: 'dynamodb',
    tableName: 'user-data',
  },
  userContext: {
    prev: {
      size: 1,
      request: {
        intent: true,
        state: true,
        inputs: true,
        timestamp: true,
      },
      response: {
        speech: true,
        reprompt: true,
        state: true,
      },
    },
  },
};

const app = new App(config);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi there! Have you updated the `jovo-framework` package to the newest version? `npm install jovo-framework --save`

Comment: @JanKönig I was using jovo-framework 1.0.0 and running the installation again seemed to fix the issue ! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of the [User Context Object](https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/data/user#context) of the Jovo Framework, you need to have at least `v1.2.0` of the `jovo-framework`.

You can update the package to the latest version like this: `npm install jovo-framework --save`

(This used to be a comment. Just adding this as an answer so other people see it as well)

Comment: Awesome! Marked as answer!